# Why I cannot use Konva.Image() in Konva.Shape.fillPatternImage(imageObj)?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, html5-canvas, kineticjs

The following is an example from [Konvajs](http://konvajs.github.io/docs/shapes/Image.html) library to load an image:

```
var imageObj = new Image();
imageObj.onload = function() {

  var yoda = new Konva.Image({
    x: 50,
    y: 50,
    image: imageObj,
    width: 106,
    height: 118
});

  And here is my code

  

  var annotation = new Konva.Line({
    points: this.contour,
    stroke: color,
    closed: true,
    strokeWidth: 1
});
  var nativeImageObject = new Image();
  nativeImageObject.onload = function() {
      var konvaImage = new Konva.Image({
        image: nativeImageObject
    });
      annotation.fillPatternImage(konvaImage);   
          DentalChart.Pattern.customPatternImages.push(customPatternImage);
      gridLayer.add(annotation);
      stage.draw();
  };
  nativeImageObject.src = pattern.toDataURL();
  nativeImageObject.id = patternEnum + '' + color;
```

Why it keep logging Uncaught TypeError: Failed to execute 'createPattern' on 'CanvasRenderingContext2D': The provided value is not of type '(HTMLImageElement or HTMLVideoElement or HTMLCanvasElement or ImageBitmap)'

```
  Call Stack Trace:

  console.trace()
  (anonymous function) @ VM11965:1evaluate @ (program):493
  InjectedScript._evaluateOn @ VM11739:875
  InjectedScript._evaluateAndWrap @ VM11739:808InjectedScript.evaluateOnCallFrame @ VM11739:933
  Konva.Context.createPattern @ konva.js:1805Konva.SceneContext._fillPattern @ konva.js:1987
  Konva.SceneContext._fill @ konva.js:2045Konva.Context.fillStrokeShape @ konva.js:1635
  Konva.Line._sceneFunc @ konva.js:12613Konva.Util.addMethods.drawScene @ konva.js:7997
  (anonymous function) @ konva.js:7675Konva.Collection.each @ konva.js:664
  Konva.Util.addMethods._drawChildren @ konva.js:7674
  Konva.Util.addMethods.drawScene @ konva.js:7629
  Konva.Util.addMethods.drawScene @ konva.js:10363
  (anonymous function) @ konva.js:7675
  Konva.Collection.each @ konva.js:664
  Konva.Util.addMethods._drawChildren @ konva.js:7674
  Konva.Util.addMethods.drawScene @ konva.js:7629
  Konva.Util.addMethods.draw @ konva.js:3799
  Konva.Util.addMethods.draw @ konva.js:9337(anonymous function) @ DentalChartLib.js:132DentalChart.Pattern.getCustomPattern.nativeImageObject.onload @ DentalChartLib.js:617
  undefined
```

Answer (score 0):

For `fillPatternImage` use native `Image` object.

http://konvajs.github.io/docs/styling/Fill.html

Comment: But how can I make operation on native `Image` object as `Konva.Image` object? I need to re-color it again efficiently?

Comment: Also you can try to use <canvas> object for `fillPatternImage`. On that canvas you can draw anything you want.

Comment: What about konva filters, how can I use them on that object?